# DRY - How Can I Combine These jQuery Functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I'm looking at this ENORMOUS block of code that I KNOW can be slimmed by about 90%. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Here's the block I'm referring to:

```
$('table.model a').click(function(){
var divForm = [$('div.form')];
$(this).closest('div').not('.close').fadeOut(500).animate({"top": "-414px"}, 100).fadeIn('fast');
    if ($(this).hasClass('tmi48')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.tmi48').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi416')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.tmi416').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi432')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.tmi432').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi464')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.tmi464').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi4s16')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.tmi4s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi4s32')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.tmi4s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi4s64')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.tmi4s64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi516')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.tmi516').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi532')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.tmi532').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi564')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.tmi564').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi5c16')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.tmi5c16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi5c32')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.tmi5c32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi5c64')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.tmi5c64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi5s16')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.tmi5s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi5s32')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.tmi5s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('tmi5s64')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.tmi5s64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti48')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.atti48').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti416')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.atti416').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti432')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.atti432').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti464')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.atti464').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti4s16')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.atti4s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti4s32')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.atti4s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti4s64')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.atti4s64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti516')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.atti516').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti532')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.atti532').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti564')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.atti564').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti5c16')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.atti5c16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti5c32')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.atti5c32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti5c64')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.atti5c64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti5s16')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.atti5s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti5s32')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.atti5s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('atti5s64')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.atti5s64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi48')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.vzi48').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi416')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.vzi416').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi432')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.vzi432').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi464')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.vzi464').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi4s16')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.vzi4s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi4s32')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.vzi4s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi4s64')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.vzi4s64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi516')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.vzi516').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi532')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.vzi532').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi564')) {
        $('img.i5').show();
        $('h1.vzi564').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi5c16')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.vzi5c16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi5c32')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.vzi5c32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi5c64')) {
        $('img.i5c').show();
        $('h1.vzi5c64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi5s16')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.vzi5s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi5s32')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.vzi5s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('vzi5s64')) {
        $('img.i5s').show();
        $('h1.vzi5s64').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli48')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.uli48').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli416')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.uli416').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli432')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.uli432').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli464')) {
        $('img.i4').show();
        $('h1.uli464').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli4s16')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.uli4s16').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli4s32')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.uli4s32').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('uli4s64')) {
        $('img.i4s').show();
        $('h1.uli4s64').show();
    } else {
        return;
    }
    divForm[0].animate({"top": "+=557px"}, 500, function(){
        $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
    }); 
});
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6YUuT/

As you can see, each link is calling the same form, but the header and image change based on which link was clicked.I've tried playing around with shared classes, but I just can't come up with a fix that works.

REVISIONS & NEW QUESTION:

I've ALMOST got all the functions worked out properly, but I ran into my original problem, this time in a different spot. I've got another enormous code block that needs to go away and though it seems almost identical to the last one, it's different enough that I haven't been able to come up with a solution that works.

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Pr8L/

And the offending/offensive code block:

```
function linkHide() {
    //var r = /(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|sp|ul)(app?|bb?|htc?|lg?|mot?|sam?))(?: |$)/;
    if ($('span.tm').is(':visible') && $('span.app').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.tmapp').show();
    } 
    if ($('span.tm').is(':visible') && $('span.bb').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.tmbb').show();
    }
    if ($('span.tm').is(':visible') && $('span.htc').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.tmhtc').show();
    }
    if ($('span.tm').is(':visible') && $('span.lg').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.tmlg').show();
    }
    if ($('span.tm').is(':visible') && $('span.mot').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.tmmot').show();
    }
    if ($('span.tm').is(':visible') && $('span.sam').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.tmsam').show();
    }
    if ($('span.att').is(':visible') && $('span.app').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.attapp').show();
    }
    if ($('span.att').is(':visible') && $('span.bb').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.attbb').show();
    }
    if ($('span.att').is(':visible') && $('span.htc').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.atthtc').show();
    }
    if ($('span.att').is(':visible') && $('span.lg').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.attlg').show();
    }
    if ($('span.att').is(':visible') && $('span.mot').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.attmot').show();
    }
    if ($('span.att').is(':visible') && $('span.sam').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.attsam').show();
    }
    if ($('span.vz').is(':visible') && $('span.app').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.vzapp').show();
    }
    if ($('span.vz').is(':visible') && $('span.bb').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.vzbb').show();
    }
    if ($('span.vz').is(':visible') && $('span.htc').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.vzhtc').show();
    }
    if ($('span.vz').is(':visible') && $('span.lg').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.vzlg').show();
    }
    if ($('span.vz').is(':visible') && $('span.mot').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.vzmot').show();
    }
    if ($('span.vz').is(':visible') && $('span.sam').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.vzsam').show();
    }
    if ($('span.ul').is(':visible') && $('span.app').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.ulapp').show();
    }
    if ($('span.ul').is(':visible') && $('span.bb').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.ulbb').show();
    }
    if ($('span.ul').is(':visible') && $('span.htc').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.ulhtc').show();
    }
    if ($('span.ul').is(':visible') && $('span.lg').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.ullg').show();
    }
    if ($('span.ul').is(':visible') && $('span.mot').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.ulmot').show();
    }
    if ($('span.ul').is(':visible') && $('span.sam').is(':visible')) {
        $('td.ulsam').show();
    }
};
```

I've now slimmed down the HTML so that ALL the table data exists in ONE table with variable headers, images and links. I was able to edit wared's regex so that it returns the proper strings, but I could not think of a way to actually USE it.

Comment: Start from scratch, it's too late for DRY I think.

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP asks for. At least in context of this code block.

Comment: haha you are exactly right, you cant do a lot more

Comment: How about using three different classes, instead of one class that tries to refer to three different variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that there can be only one of these classes per anchor. In this case, a regular expression allows you to extract this class from the class attribute, and extract the image class from it at the same time (`this` refers to the anchor element) :

```
var r = /(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(i\d[a-z]?)\d\d?)(?: |$)/;
var m = $(this).attr('class').match(r);
if (m) {
    $('img.' + m[2]).show();
    $('h1.' + m[1]).show();
} else {
    return;
}
```

The regular expression :

```
(?:^| )            the beginning of the string or a whitespace
(...)              capture -> group 1 : the heading class
(?:tm|att|vz|ul)   any of these prefixes, one time
(...)              capture -> group 2 : the image class
i\d[a-z]?          "i" + one digit + any letter, zero or one times
\d\d?              one or two digits
(?: |$)            a whitespace or the end of the string
```

To summarize :

```
"tm" or "att" or "vz" or "ul"
+ "i" + one digit + zero or one letter (group 2, example : "i4s")
+ one or two digits
```

This will match strings like `tmi416`, `atti4s16` or `vzi48`. To make things a bit more clear, you can open your browser console and paste the following code into it :

```
'foo atti4s16 bar'.match(
    /(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(i\d[a-z]?)\d\d?)(?: |$)/
)
```

You can see that an array is returned containing both the heading class (index 1 = group 1) and the image class (index 2 = group 2) :

```
[" atti4s16 ", "atti4s16", "i4s"]
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems like the most streamlined, but my current js vocabulary includes almost none of that :O I appreciate the input, though!

Comment: @user3127799 I've tried to clarify a bit :) Hard to do better though :/

Comment: I'm gonna have to study this a LOT :) So, `?:` represents a sort of inline if/else statement? And a regular expression, in its entirety is enclosed in `/ expression here /`?

Comment: @user3127799 Not a lot :) This `/pattern/` is called a regular expression. `/pat(subpattern)tern/` captures the content of the parenthesis, `/pat(?:subpattern)tern/` prevents capturing. Further reading : http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml.

Comment: I think I see how this accomplishes what it's supposed to, even if the syntax is a bit startling to me. So, `var r` contains two indexes, one for the `h1` class and one for the `img` class and `var m` matches the clicked object with one of those indexes. Is that right?

Comment: @user3127799 `r` is an object of a specific type called "RegExp". The `match` function uses it to search inside the class attribute and returns an array of strings which is assigned to `m`. The first element is the full pattern, the following ones are the sub-patterns (group 1 and 2).

Comment: This is definitely the route I want to take as I fill in the rest of the content. One more question: index 1 will remain constant, but index 2 is variable, so will I need to declare `r` with a different index 2 each time, or can I just add more indexes to `r`?

Comment: @user3127799 What's your browser?

Comment: @user3127799 With Chrome : press F12 > choose the "Console" tab > paste `'foo tmi416 bar'.match(/(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(i\d[a-z]?)\d\d?)(?: |$)/)` > press ENTER. Redo the same with `'foo vzi48 bar'` instead of `'foo tmi416 bar'`, and so on with several classes until you start to figure out what's going on.

Comment: so THAT'S what the console is for :) Told you I'm a newbie. I see that the console is returning what I'm trying to match with the matching characters in each of the two indexes. My question is if I have other classes, such as `.tmsgs4` or `.vzbbz10`can I just add more conditions to index 2, or will I have to write separate expressions?

Comment: @user3127799 Identify the recurring patterns then update the regex accordingly. Example : replace `(i\d[a-z]?)` with `(i\d[a-z]?|sgs\d|bbz\d\d)` (`|` means "or", `\d` means "one digit").

Comment: Haha, I worded that question poorly, but you nevertheless answered the question I INTENDED to ask :) Thanks a ton, this has been tremendously helpful.

Comment: @user3127799 You're welcome :) Hope I didn't mess up your brain :D

Comment: This code assumes several things that the OP's code does not and that the OP did not explain was OK.  1) It assumes there won't be more than one class matching the regex pattern on any given object where the second match is the one you actually want to process and the first is not one you want to process.  2) It assumes that there are no other class names that match the pattern that the OP does NOT want to process.

Comment: @jfriend00: Please check my HTML in the jsFiddle I linked to in my OP and let me know if you disagree, but it seems like this solution will accomplish exactly what I need with ultimately much less code. These class names are unique to the anchors and images called in this function (if they're not, I've made a mistake). I think I've managed to sorta figure out how a regexp works syntactically, and this is what it looks like when I add some stuff to it: `'foo tmlgd801 bar'.match(/(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(i\d[a-z]?\d\d?|htcone[a-z]?|gs\d|bb[a-z]?\d\d?\d\d?|lg[a-z]\d\d\d))(?: |$)/)`

Comment: @jfriend00: One advantage I can see to the array solution is that the code, while there would be much more of it, would be easier to read from an outsider's perspective. That array, however, would ultimately contain around 200 classes (a unique one for each phone model).

Comment: @MyCompassSpins - yeah, I agree.  Everyone makes their own tradeoffs in terms of readability.  I prioritize it pretty highly both so I can understand my own code years from now and so others that might work on the same code can also easily understand it.  If you want to use the regex and feel it meets your readability and maintainability needs, that's your choice.   Something a lot easier might be to just preface all operative classes with something like "xxx-" and then just find the one class that has that prefix and process that class name.  That would decomplicate the regex some.

Answer (score 2):

Now that your question is completely different, here's further optimization that again puts most of the data into data structure and then avoids duplicated code by just looping over the data structure:

```
function linkHide() {

    var atts = ["tm", "att", "vz", "ul"];
    var mfrs = ["app", "bb", "htc", "lg", "mot", "sam"];

    for (var i = 0; i < atts.length; i++) {
        if ($("span." + atts[i]).is(':visible')) {
            for (var j = 0; j < mfrs.length; j++) {
                if ($("span." + mfrs[j]).is(':visible')) {
                    $("td" + "." + atts[i] + mfrs[j]).show();
                }
            }                
        }
    } 
};
```

---

This was the answer to an original question which has now been completed changed/edited to something different:

You can put all the classes in an array and walk through the array to condense it down to this:

```
$('table.model a').click(function(){
    var classList = ['tmi416', 'tmi432', ... put other classes here];
    var divForm = [$('div.form')];
    var self = $(this);
    self.closest('div').not('.close').fadeOut(500).animate({"top": "-414px"}, 100).fadeIn('fast');
    for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
        if (self.hasClass(classList[i])) {
            // figure out class name to show
            // algorithm is to remove chars before first "i" and 
                    //    then remove trailing 16,32 or 64
            var name = classList[i].replace(/^.*?i/, "i").replace(/16$|32$|64$/,"");
            $(".img." + name).show();
            $("h1." + classList[i]).show();
            break;
        }
    }
    divForm[0].animate({"top": "+=557px"}, 500, function(){
        $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
    }); 
});
```

Or, if you put a common prefix of `"xxx-"` on the target classnames, you can do it like this without having to build the long list of class names ahead of time:

```
$('table.model a').click(function(){
    var divForm = [$('div.form')];
    var self = $(this);
    self.closest('div').not('.close').fadeOut(500).animate({"top": "-414px"}, 100).fadeIn('fast');
    var classes = " " + this.className + " ";
    var match = classes.match(/\sxxx-([^ ]+)(i[^ ]+)(\d\d)\s/);
    if (match) {
        $(".img." + match[1] + match[2]).show();
        $("h1." + match[1] + match[2] + match[3]).show();
    }
    divForm[0].animate({"top": "+=557px"}, 500, function(){
        $(this).animate({"top": "-=20px"}, 200);
    }); 
});
```

If we saw the actual HTML and understood the overall problem, you can probably simplify this much more by changing how you organize your HTML or what classes you use or by putting custom attributes on some elements.  But, that requires us seeing much more of what you're doing than just rewriting the one block of code.

Comment: Definitely looking for something like this. Let me play around with it a bit and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: just make it an object: `"tmi48" : "img.i4, h1.tmi48", ...` You check if the key exists as class and call `show()` on the value...

Comment: @onetrickpony - that was my fallback, but I found an algorithmic conversion that saves all that typing.

Comment: @user3127799 - OK, I edited it to handle the variable class name.

Comment: Exactly what I need with the `h1`s. I understand academically what you're doing with that algorithm (removing the number from the end of the class name to get the `img` name), but I've never seen any of that syntax before. (I've only been coding for about 4 months.) I'll play around with that some more and get back to you. Much obliged!

Comment: @jfriend00: Perfect! The suggestions below seem to accomplish this without the huge array of all my classes, but as a total newbie, I can't look at the code and see right away what it does. This works and I understand WHY it works and that's important. Thank you!

Comment: @user3127799 - wared's solution makes several guesses/assumptions about your situation that my solution does not.  The other answers all have a list of classes in them (actually they use a map of all the classes).  If I was doing this myself, I'd select the class names so the entire thing could be algorithmic with no risk from a known type of class name.  But, with the hand you dealt us and not making blind assumptions about the HTML, this is the cleanest rewrite of that code you had I could find.

Comment: @jfriend00: I'd definitely be interested in further suggestions. You can see my HTML in the jsFiddle I included at the bottom of that horrendous code block.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins - I added an option without the class name list to my answer.

Comment: Interesting. Although, since I will have as many classes as phone models it seems like this would end up becoming quite cluttered. It's incredibly helpful for me to see all the different possible paths to the same spot, though. Being a beginner and being self-taught, I find that my major failing is not a lack of knowledge, but the ability to figure out how to apply that knowledge to my project. Even if I don't use this for my current project, this is undoubtedly something I will use.

Comment: @jfriend00: I updated my OP to include your and wared's suggestions, which were all tremendously helpful. Of course my ineptitude in certain areas still shines impressively :)

Comment: @MyCompassSpins - In case you don't quite follow how StackOverflow works, you should NOT edit your question to change it into an entirely different question.  Now most of our answers look like they have little to do with your current question which makes the whole Q&A of little use to follow on readers.  It's fine to use the edit button to clarify your question, but if you're going to wholesale change things, you should either start a new question or add new info onto the end of the question.  As it stands now, our answers look like they have nothing to do with your current question.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins - what you have now in your question is an entirely different question than you started with.  Our current answers no longer apply at all.

Comment: @jfriend00: speaking of my ineptitude. Taken care of.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins - I made one further edit to my answer - please look at that.

Comment: @jfriend00: Perfect! In my own attempts, I had those two arrays and was trying to loop through them simultaneously. It looks like it can be done if you loop through them sequentially instead. I always wrack my brain for hours, and then when I see it done by someone who knows what they're doing, it seems so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map of objects to classes:

IE:

```
var map = {
  "uli48": {
          img: "i4",
          h1: "uli48"
        }
}
```

then you can loop along the lines of

```
var cls, classList = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");

for(var i=0; i<classList.length; i++) {
   cls = classList[i];
   if(map[cls]) {
      $("h1"+cls.h1).show();
      $("img"+cls.img).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm unfamiliar with object maps and the `.split()` method. However it looks like this is similar to the answer I went with except that here there would be a map of all my classes instead of an array. Is that right?

Comment: Yes thats right, I didn't write out everything.  The `map` in this case is just a plain javascript object.  Its used as a map in the sense that you map the key (the class names) to a value (an object with the classes for the h1 and the img).  This is just a starting point to illustrate the basic concepts.  You'd still need to add the click handler and write out all the class objects correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the mentioned classes are exclusive. If you depend on the order of the if statements, you'll need some more tweaks.

First, build the dictionary of class of `this` and the associated classes:

```
var relatedImgs = { "tmi48" : "i4", ... };
```

This can be done with sed or an editor macro from your code.
Then, you need to find out classes of `this`:

```
var thisClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
```

Then just try to find the class which is in the `relatedImgs` dictionary and use the related information:

```
function findRelated(element) {
    var thisClasses = $(element).attr('class').split(' ');
    for (var i in thisClasses) {
        var imgClass = relatedImgs[thisClasses[i]];
        if (imgClass) {
            return [$("h1." + thisClasses[i]), 
                    $("img." + imgClass)];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var related = findRelated(this);
if (related !== null) {
    for (var i in related) {
        related.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is a dictionary the same as a map of objects? The syntax looks the same. So, you're creating a dictionary that equates each class to its corresponding image, is that right?

Comment: Yes, it's the very same solution as the Ben McCormick's one.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension of the following one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20926579/1636522.

So, in order to prevent the regular expression from growing more and more as your needs evolve (in other words, to keep things readable and maintainable), you could split it into smaller regular expressions, each one matching a specific device category. This results in something close to [the class list solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20926338/1636522), but the list is reduced to a few patterns :

```
var patterns = [
    '(i\\d[a-z]?)\\d\\d?', // iPhone
    '(sgs\\d)',            // Samsung Galaxy S
    '(bbz\\d\\d?)'         // Blackberry Z
];

var i = -1;
while (++i < patterns.length) {
    patterns[i] = new RegExp(
        '(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)' + patterns[i] + ')(?: |$)'
    );
}
```

You could also feed the list manually :

```
var patterns = [
    /(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(i\d[a-z]?)\d\d?)(?: |$)/,
    /(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(sgs\d))(?: |$)/,
    /(?:^| )((?:tm|att|vz|ul)(bbz\d\d?))(?: |$)/
];
```

Initialize the click event as follows :

```
$('a').click(function () {
    var cls = $(this).attr('class'),
        i = -1, 
        m;
    while (++i < patterns.length) {
        if (m = cls.match(patterns[i])) {
            $('img.' + m[2]).show();
            $('h1.' + m[1]).show();
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/UTe5F/.

Comment: while clearly bulkier, it's elegant and probably preferable from a readability standpoint. A couple questions: is `//d` the same as `/d/d`? Second, is `var m`pre-defined in JS, or is it actually being defined in the `if` statement? Third, in your fiddle, what is the default you're preventing on click? FINALLY, I'm guessing that since you must define `i` as equal to `-1`  that means `.length` is not 0-index like an array?

Comment: @MyCompassSpins `console.log('\d')` gives `"d"`, `console.log('\\d')` gives `"\d"`. `'\d'` and `'\\d'` are both strings but in the second one the backslash is escaped in order not to loose it. Why escaping `\d`? `/\d/` (literal notation) is the same as `new RegExp('\\d')` (constructor notation). In the first case, you're writing an actual regular expression, while in the second case, you're writing a string which is passed to the `RegExp` constructor for conversion, that's it.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins `m` is for `match`, not `magic` ;) This is just a variable name, you can replace it with whatever you want. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default click behaviour from occuring, that is to say, a click on a link is intended to redirect to the corresponding `href` value by default, this is not what we are interested in here. Finally, `++i` increments `i` before using it, unlike `i++`, so, the loop starts with `0` (`-1 + 1 -> 0`).

Comment: @MyCompassSpins Let me give you this advice : open your browser console (F12) as often as possible and make plenty of experiments. This is a quick and easy way to learn to know the language, the best way for an outsider. For example, why `i = -1`? Really easy to check by yourself : `var i = -1; while (++i < 3) { console.log(i); }` ;)

Comment: @MyCompassSpins A little help : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/AYtsC/. Not as useful as the browser console but useful enough for starting :)

Comment: yeah, now that I know what the console is for I've been playing around with it a lot. Your mini-console is kinda extraordinary :) I updated my OP with your suggestions implemented. As you'll see, for me, understanding the syntax and understanding how to implement it are two different things :O

Comment: @MyCompassSpins You should revert back to the previous revision for the current question and post a new question. Otherwise, I'm afraid no-one is going to help you :/

Comment: Lesson learned. I re-edited so my original post is still up top. Since there are now answers that are relevant to both questions I'm going to leave it as is and call it done. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins You're not bad as a student ;) Hopefully I was good as a teacher :D

Comment: Exceptional :) I'm consistently impressed by your and others' willingness (eagerness, even) to help.